# How do I choose which of the main Java IO classes I need to write strings to a file?

Tags: java, file, io

There are many different classes in the IO package, some seems to only have suble differences.
If you are to write some Strings to a text file, and read them for later use.
Which classes would you use for each of those two purposes and why?

- BufferedInputStream
- BufferedOutputStream
- BufferedWriter
- BufferedReader
- DataInputStream
- DataOutputStream
- FileInputStream
- FileOutputStream
- FileReader
- FileWriter
- InputStreamReader
- OutputStreamReader
- Reader
- Writer

Comment: Please provide more information. Why an array? How is that related to IO?

Comment: xs0, simply for the sake of providing a plausible scenario which would use the IO classes.
This is relatable to IO because; it is a question about which IO classes that are particular useful in such case.
I have an exam tomorrow, and the general whole code in general is the main assesment point. So not to look into a lot of different unmodern and messy classes is the goal of this question

Comment: Well, with such a general question it's hard to give any answer, and at least to me, it's unclear why one would need IO classes when dealing with arrays.. Perhaps at least name the specific classes you're looking at and what you find confusing about them?

Comment: I have redefined the question, hope this clears something up.

Comment: If you are dealing with strings then the reader/writer versions is what you will use. The "buffered" version are used for performance reasons. BTW, javadocs and pretty clear on the purpose of those classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to do.

**Output Streams**

In case you want to **write byte data**, you would use some subclass of `OutputStream` that is used to write bytes in destination defined by concrete subclass.

For example `FileOutputStream` is used to write data in file byte by byte (or bunch of bytes).

`BufferedOutputStream` is an optimized extension of `FileOutputStream` to write blocks of bytes to minimize number of disk operations. So when you call write, actually it may or may not be written in file - depends on buffer's state whether it is full or not. If buffer reaches it's max capacity, all bytes are flushed to file at once.

`ByteArrayOutputStream` is using just block of memory as a destination instead of file. Current stream content is obtained via `toByteArray()` method (why would you need such a stream will be explained later).

`ObjectOutputStream` is used to write objects (class instances) in some destination defined by the underlying `OutputStream`. For example, `ObjectOutputStream(FileOutputStream)` would write an objects in file, while `ObjectOutputStream(ByteArrayOutputStream)` would write an objects in memory. The last option allows you to serialize objects in byte buffer (array of bytes) which can be then send somewhere via network.

Note, that any object you want to write somewhere via `ObjectOutputStream` has to implement `Serializable` interface. Since object may contain references to another objects, all the objects that are accessible from the object to be serialized also has to implement `Serializable` interface as **serialization**, by default, is process of writting of **full graph of objects** - assuming you are not using `transient` keyword to exclude class field from serialization, or you are not defining at object's class a special methods `writeObject/readObject` that overrides default serialization behaviour. These methods are designed to implement custom serialization i. e. you can define on your own how to write/read class field in/from  `ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream`. Suppose class `A` for which you are implementing custom serialization contains an object of class `B`. Instead of writting object `b` as a full graph, i. e. instead of calling `oos.writeObject(b)`, where `oos` is an argument of the `writeObject` method being implemented in class `A`,  you would write in stream only some fields of class `B` e. g. `oos.writeBoolean(b.isEnabled)`, `oos.writeInt(b.value)`. As long as object `b` is not written via `oos.writeObject(b)`, it does not have to implement `Serializable` interface. For more details see `Serializable` documentation.

`DataOutputStream` is used to write primitives like *boolean*, *char*, *int*, *long*, *float*, *double*. Since any object can be decomposed to primitives e. g. `class A { int i = 0; B b = new B();}`, `class B {double d = 0.0;}` can be written simply as `int a, double d`, you can use `DataOutputStream` to serialize objects in compressed way unlike serialization which writes much more data e. g. class path, class version, ... so `ClassLoader` can identify a given class in runtime, instantiate this class and finally load data to this empty object. Note that instantiating class by it's name + initialising object in this way is much slower than instantiating class on your own and initializing it's fields on your own from "raw" `DataOutputStream` (that's why OS Android prefers custom `Parcelable` interface over standard serialization, which works as writting/reading to/from `DataOutputStream/DataInputStream`).

In case you want to **write string data**, you would use `OutputStreamWriter` a higher level of output-stream  which writes characters/Strings in destination defined by `OutputStream` (in case of writting in file, you would pass `FileOutputStream`, in case of writtin in memory you would pass `ByteArrayOutputStream`).

`FileWriter` is an extension of `OutputStreamWriter` designed for writting in file.

`BufferedWriter` works the same as `BufferedOutputStream` except it is designed for work with strings and characters.

`CharArrayWriter` works the same as `ByteArrayOutputStream` except characters are stored in `char[]` which is obtained by calling `getCharArray()`.

`StringWriter` is similar to `CharArrayWriter` except it allows you to write strings which are stored in `StringBuffer` that is obtained by calling     `getBuffer()`.

`PrintWriter` allows you to write formatted strings in specified destination defined by `OutputStream` (this writer is designed for easy logging).

**Input Streams**

The same concept is applied to input-streams (readers) associated with given output-streams (writers) mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

- Readers and InputStreams are for input while Writers and OutputStreams are for output.
- Readers and Writers are for text (with a character set) while InputStreams and OutputStreams are for binary data (such as images).
- Buffering helps with performance because reads and writes are batched rather than making a system call each time any method is used.
- If it has "File" in the name, it is used for files.

So for your specific case you want to write text to a file, the most obvious candidate is a FileWriter:

```
Writer out = new FileWriter(
    new File("foo.txt")
);
```

If you want better performance for making many small writes to it, you could wrap it in a buffer:

```
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(
    new FileWriter(
        new File("foo.txt")
    )
);
```

The FileWriter assumes the default character encoding when writing text.  If you want to choose the encoding, or ensure that it is consistent on all platforms, you could create the writer from an OutputStream specifying the encoding explicitly:

```
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(
            new File("foo.txt")
        ), "UTF-8"
    )
);
```